# Gulp Browser-Sync CannotGet

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Всем привет, и легкого кодинга, помогите решить проблему. с Gulp Browser-Sync. При запуске таска браузер выдает ошибку Cannot GET. 
Пробывал пути в basedir указывать, и через конфиг и так>>. Не работает, буду признателен в помощи.

P.S камни не бросайте, первый раз ставлю Gulp. Документацию прочел.

```html
var gulp = require ('gulp');
var less = require ('gulp-less');
var smart = require ('smart-grid');
var broser = require ('browser-sync')

//Общий конфиг way Folders

var config = {

 src: './app',
 css: {

  src: 'app/*.less',
  dest: 'app/css'
 }

}

gulp.task('less',function () {
 
 return gulp.src('app/')
 .pipe(less())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/css'))
 .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
})


gulp.task('browsers',function () {
 
broser({

 server: {

  baseDir: './app'
 },

  port: 8080

})

})

gulp.task('watch',function () {
 
 gulp.watch(config.src + config.css.src, [less]);
})
```

Comment: а в `./app` есть `index.html`?

Comment: Да, есть... я уже все перепробовал. По разному пути прописывал, и массивом и так. Запускал Browser-sync через прокси, одна беда..

Comment: не беда, нормально работает. просто делать нужно по инструкции. а в вопросе не достаточно данных чтобы помочь.

Comment: Да, согласен, натупил с функциией browsersync.reload . Въехал, разобрался. Спасибо, что отозвались.

Comment: https://webdesign-master.ru/blog/tools/2016-03-09-gulp-beginners.html

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался.